# Sharepoint Alerts to users not in sharepoint

Tags: 2010

I would like to send an alert to a user that is not part of the SharePoint site group.
It would be to personal e-mail address.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this by creating a custom workflow in SharePoint Designer 2010.  What is the business logic that will drive the alert?